# Calling Azure IoT Hub from IPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I followed the Azure IoT tutorial at:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted/

and everything works great.

I now have a new requirement, which is to connect to the IoT hub from an iPhone. In the C# example, I had to download the appropriate NuGet package (Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client) and use the `DeviceClient` class.

Is there a similar "package" available for iPhone development? How can an iOS device connect to the Azure IoT hub?

Answer (score 1):

There's a [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt590785.aspx) for devices to exchange messages with an Azure IOT Hub.

Answer (score 1):

The Azure IoT Hub C# Device SDK is now cross-platform (with Xamarin), and supports iOS devices.

It's published as a nuget package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.PCL/